# Use write() to read stdin/file and print lines - doesn't show number of lines

Tags: c

I can make it mirror the line. I tried to print the line with printf, doesn't work because its buffered and only prints when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

I'm trying with `write()` but no output is showing. Why not? I have to use system calls. And if it's a simple thing after the line print, how can I add a space after the number?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n, i = 0;
    char buf[1];
    int reader=0;

    if(argc > 1){
       reader = open(argv[2],O_RDONLY);
    }

    while(n = read(reader,buf,sizeof(buf)) > 0) {
       if (buf[0] == '\n') { 
          i++; 
          write(1, &i,sizeof(i));
       }
       write(1,buf,sizeof(buf));
    }
    close(reader);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `write(1, &i,sizeof(i));` This doesn't write in a human-readable format. If you want to be able to see the number you need to convert it to a string and write that.

Comment: @n.m. tried the cast to (char) with no sucess. any ideia how?

Comment: Casting to `char` and converting to a string are two totally different things. You should almost never use casts. To convert a number to a string, try `sprintf`.

Comment: @n.m. did that and same problem with printf, since its buffered it only prints after the write :|

Comment: If you want to ask a separate question about a buffering problem with `printf`, hit the "Ask a question" button and don't forget to include code that has `printf`. However `sprintf` is not `printf`, it doesn't do file IO and has nothing to do with buffering.

Comment: this line: `reader = open(argv[2],O_RDONLY);` is assuming that the value of `argc` is 3 or greater, but the prior code only assure the value of `argc` is 2 or greater.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: to have the output immediately show on the terminal, either 1) keep outputting until the I/O buffer overflows (bad idea) or 2) trail each write with a write of '\n' or 3) call the function: `fflush( stdout );`

Comment: you ask: *how can I add a space after the number*   What number?  all the current code is doing is echoing the input char to the output.  One possibility is to use `char mystring[10]; sprintf( mystring, "%d \n", (int)buf[0] );  write(  1, mystring, strlen( mystring ) );`

Comment: @user3629249 the argv[2] is that i'm assuming there will be no input/usage errors (kind of redundant to check that first, then :) )

Comment: @user3629249 will try and read about the fflush 

the number is the number of line, i could had explained the code a little better tough

Comment: Never assume that user will do/enter the right/expected data.
So, it is not 'redundant' to check to assure the command line parameters were actually entered.

Comment: regarding the contents of `argv[]`   argv[0] is the name of the executable  argv[1] is the first parameter  argv[2] is the second parameter.  The posted code does not use `argv[1]` at all!  Why not?  the `argc` counter indicates how many entries are in the `argv[]` array.  I'm thinking that you have a misunderstanding about `argc` and the contents of `argv[]`

Comment: regarding this line: `write(1, &i,sizeof(i));`  the variable `i` is not printable/readable.   instead 1) output the '\n' (this will also force the prior characters to be output to the terminal) 2) use something like `printf( "%d ", i );` to output the `i` (and a space) in a readable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one version of the program that works correctly

Notice the proper timing of the 'line number' at the beginning of a line, including the first line and no extra line number output after the last line

Notice the usage of the high level I/O rather than the low level `read()` and `write()`

Notice the checking for missing command line parameter

Notice the usage statement to stderr when command line parameter missing

Notice the error checking and proper error message to stderr when `fopen()` fails

Notice that each indent level is consistent and 4 spaces wide

Notice the usage of a variable 'priorCh' to track when the line number needs to be output.

Notice the proper referencing of the `main()` parameters `argc` and `argv[]`

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), fopen(), fclose(), fgetc(), putc(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE





int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int      i = 0;       // line counter
    int      ch;
    int      priorCh = '\0';

    FILE*    reader= NULL;  // init to an invalid value

    if( 1 == argc )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <inputFileName> \n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of command line parameters


    reader = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if( NULL == reader )
    {
        perror( "fopen for input file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, open successful

    i++;
    printf( "%d ", i );

    while( (ch = fgetc( reader ) ) != EOF )
    {
        if( '\n' == priorCh )
        {
            i++;
            printf( "%d ", i );
        }
        putc( ch, stdout );
        priorCh = ch;
    } // end while

    fclose(reader);
    return 1;
} // end function: main
```

Here is the output, when using the above file as the input

```
1 #include <stdio.h>   // printf(), fopen(), fclose(), fgetc(), putc(), perror()
2 #include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
9 {
10 
11     int      i = 0;       // line counter
12     int      ch;
13     int      priorCh = '\0';
14 
15     FILE*    reader= NULL;  // init to an invalid value
16 
17     if( 1 == argc )
18     {
19         fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <inputFileName> \n", argv[0] );
20         exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
21     }
22 
23     // implied else, correct number of command line parameters
24 
25 
26     reader = fopen(argv[1], "r");
27     if( NULL == reader )
28     {
29         perror( "fopen for input file failed" );
30         exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
31     }
32 
33     // implied else, open successful
34 
35     i++;
36     printf( "%d ", i );
37 
38     while( (ch = fgetc( reader ) ) != EOF )
39     {
40         if( '\n' == priorCh )
41         {
42             i++;
43             printf( "%d ", i );
44         }
45         putc( ch, stdout );
46         priorCh = ch;
47     } // end while
48 
49     fclose(reader);
50     return 1;
51 } // end function: main
```

Comment: notice that the number of characters in the 'line number' causes a variant in the first column of the echo'd file lines. which is not desirable.

Comment: notice the placement of the literal, when being compared via the `==` operator is on the left, so a keypunch error like using `=` will be caught by the compiler rather than the programmer spending their time and energy trying to debug the program.

Comment: notice a weakness in this answer as it makes the assumption that there will be (at least) one line in the input file.

Comment: the intent was to use read/write(). i'm supposed to only use system calls.

Comment: will mark has the best answer though. thank you for your time.